# Из какой репы идет пакет «pass» в astra linux?

Tags: linux, docker, debian, astra-linux

Устанавливаю Docker Desktop на Astra Linux 1.7 Орел (основано на ядре debian 10)
устанавливаю по этой инструкции - https://docs.docker.com/desktop/linux/install/debian/
и когда дело доходит уже до установки самого пакета

> sudo apt-get install ./docker-desktop--.deb

то мне выдает ошибку
E: Для пакета «pass» не найден кандидат на установку, скрин прилагаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я так понимаю что в репах которые у меня указаны, система не видит этот пакет, так вот вопрос, как установить этот пакет? или ошибка вообще совсем в другом и я что-то не понимаю?
скрин реп
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: описанные тут шаги выполняли ? https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/#set-up-the-repository

Comment: раз потащили докер в орла, то притащите и pass. https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/pass

Answer (score 0):

Добавил эту репу, и вытащил оттуда pass

> deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster main

Comment: Пытаться смешать пакеты двух разных дистрибутивов — обычно плохая идея, которая может окончиться смертью системы

Comment: @andreymal импортозамещение по-русски :)